# Django admin: how to filter records by datetime ranges using a url GET parameter?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have records with a timestamp field, and I'd like to filter their Django admin view by datetime ranges.

I'm looking for something like adding to the url `?timestamp__lt=201012310715&timestamp__gte=201012300715`

^ this doesn't work..

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it works if you specify the datetime in the following format:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

The query string would then look something like:

`?datetime_field__lt=2010-09-28+21:00:59&datetime_field__gt=2010-09-22+00:00:00`

Actually, I have no idea why only this format is working and if this will continue to work like this in future releases.