# How to pass a timestamp format parameter using NodeJS's http?

Tags: node.js, rest, http

I'm using NodeJS to build a RESTful application, and NodeJS's `http` module (documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)) to handle requests.

I didn't have any problems handling requests so far, nor passing parameters, such as `?name=joe`, `?category=worker`, or `?name=joe&category=worker`.

However, I'm having problems filtering dates in the ISO format, such as 2017-04-13T18:35:49.924Z. When I use `?timestamp=2017-04-13T18:35:49.924Z`, for example, nothing is returned.

I know that there are modules and APIs that can filter timestamps, such as what was shown in [this question regarding Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582780/django-admin-how-to-filter-records-by-datetime-ranges-using-a-url-get-parameter), and [this other question of tableau usage](https://community.tableau.com/thread/123061). They can even handle operators of greater than or less than, as shown in [this page](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).

Can I filter timestamps using `http` module? Are there greater than and less than operators, for example, or do I have to find another module?

What I want to achieve with this is to filter by timestamp the records being shown in the view.

Comment: By "When I use `?timestamp=2017-04-13T18:35:49.924Z`, for example, nothing is returned.", do you want to extract the `timestamp` value in Node.js? Can you attach your current code?

Comment: There is a function that returns the logs via the following URL:

`return $http.get("/log?levelStr=INFO&category=intService");`

And there are no problems. But when I try to use:

`return $http.get("/log?timestamp=2017-04-13T18:35:49.924Z");`

Nothing is returned.

Comment: You need to check server side logic. It seems the ` GET /log` API does not support `timestamp` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `http` module has nothing to do with filtering or comparing timestamps. However, this is built in to JavaScript. It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do, but yes you can easily compare JavaScript dates. (Note that you will have to convert your timestamps in JavaScript Date objects)

```
var x = new Date('2017-04-13T18:35:49.924Z');
var y = new Date('2017-05-13T18:35:49.924Z');
x > y // false
x < y // true
```

Comment: Are you sure $http module has nothing to do with filtering? Because, as mentioned in the question's comment, I use return `$http.get("/log?levelStr=INFO&category=intService");` to get the filtered logs. 

I know that I can use JavaScript to compare dates, but I would prefer to get the filtered results via URL directly.

Comment: No, the `http` module does not do any filtering like this. It's unclear what you're doing exactly, and where this data is being fetched from, but the query params must be extracted and passed into some kind of logic (database query, etc) in order to fetch and/or filter the proper data

Comment: The URL is being used to fetch data from a database. In the case of `return $http.get("/log?levelStr=INFO&category=intService");`, all the logs that have `levelStr=INFO` and `category=intService` are being returned from the database.

Comment: Then those query params are being passed into a DB query. Your dates need to be passed into that query as well. This lives somewhere in your server side logic, presumably a controller function that handles requests to the `/log` endpoint.